# Server could not parse JSON when exclamation mark is present

Tags: php, json, api, curl, zendesk

I'm trying to submit a small amount of data to the ZenDesk api.  This works fine 99% of the time, the only issue occurs when an exclamation mark is present in the text.

I'm using the following to add the record:

```
$company_name = "Company Name!";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,"https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/organizations.json");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$body = '{"organization": {"name": "'.$company_name.'","domain_names": ["'.$company_url.'"]}}';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$body);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
'Content-Type: application/json',
'Connection: Keep-Alive'
));
```

Comment: Does the same issue occured when you use json_encode with an array?

Comment: This is not a JSON issue, this is a validation issue and probably in the backend of the service you are using

Comment: Maby if you replace the exclamation mark with HTML entity &#33; ...?

Comment: What is the exact error message you get?

Answer (score -1):

A few libraries I've tested to read and write JSON seem to automatically escape any exclamation mark ("!") when writing to a JSON file.
The libraries can still read the exclamation mark even if it's not escaped, but they seems to prefer to escape it as a precaution.

While searching online, I've seen anecdotal evidence of problems with exclamation marks in JSON that weren't escaped. But no hard evidence of a known issue.

In doubt, I would recommend always escaping exclamation marks in JSON as a precaution.